# Plugin with id 'com.wonbin.myplugin' not found

Tags: gradle

I wrote a demo for learning gradle for android . i used the JAR

1) project root dir build.gradle

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
                jcenter()
                flatDir {dirs 'build_libs'}
        }

        dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
                classpath 'com.wonbin.myplugin:MyPlugin:1.0'
        }
}

apply plugin: 'com.wonbin.myplugin'

allprojects {
        repositories {
                jcenter()
        }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have leanrd that the plugin id is the properties filename  in the plugin project. But  still  when I run ./gradlew assemble , it happens:

Build file '/home/wonbin/MyApp/build.gradle' line: 13

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyApp'.
>
>   > Plugin with id 'com.wonbin.myplugin' not found.

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `build_dir` doesn't correspond to the correct file structure. You can reference your jar in the classpath directly instead, like this:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
                jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
                classpath file('/path/to/your/plugin.jar')
        }
}

apply plugin: 'com.wonbin.myplugin'
```